# Advantages of sqlite3 vs CouchDB for an application like a personal feed reader?

Tags: sqlite, couchdb

Say I wanted to build a feed reader that downloads RSS and Atom feeds to your local computer and lets you view them locally. What are the respective advantages and disadvantages of using CouchDB or sqlite3 as the datastore for such an application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good summary from rsp. Without knowing more about your requirements, it's hard to say which one is better suited for your use case. One clear advantage that SQLite provides is that is has simpler installation and administration. As a library, it's linked into your application and installed along with your application. No separate database to install and configure. This is one of the features that makes database libraries, like SQLite and Berkeley DB very attractive, and possibly preferable to database servers.

Just to add to your list of considerations, [Berkeley DB](http://bit.ly/eKvOPB) and [Berkeley DB Java Edition](http://bit.ly/dM4Qtw) are also database libraries that you may want to consider. Berkeley DB (written in C) offers you the choice of using a schema-free key-value pair API, a POJO-like Java API or a SQLite-compatible SQL API. Berkeley DB Java Edition (100% Java) offers you Java APIs for key-value pairs, Java Collections or POJO-like object persistence. Berkeley DB and SQLite tend to be the products of choice for people who are looking for embedding data management functionality inside of their application.

Disclaimer: I am the Product Manager for Berkeley DB, so I'm a little biased. :-)

Answer (score 16):

SQLite and CouchDB are probably different in every respect but what you consider an advantage or disadvantage is a matter of preference and requirements.

SQLite is an SQL database where you store relations (tables).

CouchDB is a NoSQL database where you store JSON documents (objects of any structure).

SQLite has schemas.

CouchDB is schema-less.

SQLite is a library that you link with your application and use a C API.

CouchDB is a RESTful web service and its API is HTTP and JSON.

SQLite has no concept of a network.

CouchDB basically is a high performance web server.

SQLite is written in C.

CouchDB is written in Erlang.

Which of those are advantages and disadvantages? This is up to you. ;) Good luck.